# How to instruct Ninject to use a factory method for any requested subtype of a given type?

Tags: c#, ninject, factory-method

I have a base `Dto` type where I have several common logic and code (change notifications, validations, etc.). Due to technical reasons whenever I have to create an instance of a concrete DTO type like `PersonDTO` I have to use a factory method.

```
var personDto = Dto.Create<PersonDTO>();
// or a non-generic variant like
var personDto = Dto.Create(typeof(PersonDTO));
```

Now how could I ask Ninject to use this factory method whenever I need inject any `Dto` descendant? I mean something like

```
Bind<Dto>().ToMethod(ctx => Dto.Create(ctx.Request.Service));
```

but which could get applied to not only the base `Dto` requests but also to every request for any `Dto` descendant type.

I know I could probably use the conventions Ninject extension's "for all ..." kind of feature, but I'd rather like a way without yet another library if possible.

Comment: Later I realized that my question is semantically not exactly correct because the factory method should have optional arguments to pass to the concrete constructor. However, the technical question about Ninject is still valid, so I'll leave the post unchanged for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every type which needs to be resolvable (`IResolutionRoot.Get<SomeType>()`), there needs to be a binding, for example:

```
Bind<Dto>().To..
Bind<DtoBla>().To..
```

except in case you'll do a binding with multiple types such as:

```
Bind<Dto,DtoBla>().To...
```

this overload is specifically useful when you want to bind multiple types to the same *instance*, for example if you want to have a singleton `FooBar : IFoo, IBar` resolve as `IFoo` and `IBar`.

Now in case you have to do a lot of very similar bindings, Ninject.Extensions.Conventions is just a library to make the task easier for you. You don't need to use it, you can also program type detection (using reflection) and binding creation yourself.

The reflection part has been covered many times over and over on stackoverflow, see for example:

- [Generating a list of child classes with reflection in .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896716/generating-a-list-of-child-classes-with-reflection-in-net-3-5)
- [Register all declared child classes of a class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203474/register-all-declared-child-classes-of-a-class-in-c-sharp)
- [Get all derived types of a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857705/get-all-derived-types-of-a-type)
- [Search an assembly for all child types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309071/search-an-assembly-for-all-child-types)

Of course, if you don't want to use Ninject.Extensions.Reflection, you can also just go look at its source code to see how it's done and copy the relevant parts! ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I'll just use the conventions extension I think. I was just curious if maybe there is a built-in way.

Comment: Please could you check my followup question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509906/how-to-make-ninject-use-a-custom-construction-logic-for-a-specific-type-while-ke