# How to make Ninject use a custom construction logic for a specific type while keeping the resolution process?

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a class which accepts dependencies as constructor arguments. This class may be inherited by some other classes and due to technical reasons (about constructor order and so) I have to use a factory method and dynamic invocation using `Activator.CreateInstance`. The factory method is not purely infrastructural, but it has some kind of initialization logic inside.

```
public class Foo {
  protected Foo(IService service, IOtherService otherService) { ... }
  ...
  public Foo Create(Type fooType, params object[] constructorArgs) {
    var instance (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(fooType, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.CreateInstance, constructorArgs, null, null); // or something similar...
    instance.SetDefaultValues(); // for example...
    instance.StartChangeNotifications();
    return instance;
}
```

The possible descendants can take even more dependencies, etc. I would like to still use Ninject to resolve dependencies and create the object tree.

However, using `ToMethod` binding I have to create to whole sub-tree myself. Is there any way when I could customize **only the construction** of a specific type in the resolution process?

I'd like to use it like this.

```
kernel.Bind<ConcreteFoo>().ConstructWith(ctx => Foo.Create(ctx.Request.Service, ctx.Arguments));
```

where `ConstructWith` and `ctx.Arguments` are fictional parts. I hope my problem is clear.

Comment: Why are you adamant about using `Activator.CreateInstance`? What does it do that ninject can't? Note that there's plenty of ways to parameterize ninject's reslution/construction, like the `ToConstructor` binding or `WithConstructorArgument` extensions...

Comment: I'm using it because I have other things in the factory method, I've just omitted them for clarity. I've updated my post with a few example lines. The factory method has logic in it, it's not only infrastructural code. I know that there are many ways to pass parameters to resolution, but I need a different thing here.

Comment: using `ToMethod` you still use `IContext` to create dependencies. Using `OnActivation` you can do your initialization stuff like `SetDefaultValues`..., then there's also `ToConstructor` to choose a constructor and specify what to inject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your options (with some examples):

- `ToMethod(ctx => Foo.Create(ctx.Kernel.Get<IDependency>())`
- `ToConstructor(s => new Foo(s.Inject<IDependency1>(), s.Inject<IDependency2>())`
- `WithConstructorArgument(typeof(string), "someParameter")` to just specify single arguments and use default resolution for the rest (or other, custom, paremeters)
- `OnActivation(o => o.SetDefaultValues())` to perform your post-activation logic like `SetDefaultValues`.
- alternatively: `OnActivation((IContext ctx, Foo instance) => foo.Initialize(ctx.Kernel.Get<Settings>()))`

Comment: The problem is that I would like to have one centralized factory method, accepting dynamic amount of parameters. Each descendant class can have its own parameters, so I would need to define lots of separate bindings and wouldn't even be able to use something like the conventions extension. The closest to my needs is the `OnActivation` callback, however I don't like it because I delegate too much logic to Ninject instead of only infrastructure IMO. I'll accept your answer though, thank you.